# PHP - Exit For Loop After Wrong Answer

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to teach myself PHP. My current exercise combines a form (not included in the code, but it works) that requires the user to enter the name of a city. The loop and the if statement compare the entry with an array of state capitals to return an answer that states whether that city is a state capital or not.

If I leave out the `elseif` part, the code runs ok, but I have no alternative when the user has entered a city that is not in the array. But with the `elseif`, the first part of the loop doesn't execute. For example, if I enter "Albany" without the `elseif`, I get "Albany is the capital of New York." But if I enter it with the `elseif` statement, it runs the loop until it finds "New York" and it prints "Albany is the capital of New York."

I've googled this, and I've read the books on PHP that I have. And I also know that I'm making a very basic mistake. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($stateCapitalNames); $i++)

if ($enteredCity == $stateCapitalNames[$i]) {

print "<p>$enteredCity is the capital of <b>$stateNames[$i]</b>. </p>";


} elseif ($enteredCity != $stateCapitalNames[$i]){

print "<p>$enteredCity is not the capital of a state.</p>";

}

?>
```

Comment: On a sidenote, you do not need the `else if`, you can use `else` since `$enteredCity != $stateCapitalNames[$i]` is always true at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing your brackets in your for loop. I'm surprised the elseif is the culprit and that the code doesn't fail anyways. But here is what I would do, errors aside:

```
$correct = false;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($stateCapitalNames); $i++){
    if ($enteredCity == $stateCapitalNames[$i]) {
         $correct = true;
         $stateNames = $stateNames[$i]; // Updated $stateNames variable

         break;
    }
}

//You can check $correct here...
if($correct){
    print "<p>$enteredCity is the capital of <b>$stateNames[$i]</b>. </p>"; /*Removed [$i] from  $stateNames. For some reason, $stateNames[$i] wasn't updating outside the loop, but now it is. 
}
```

This way, no matter what, until the code finds a correct answer, the user is wronge. Once it finds the right answer, it sets it as correct and exits the loop by setting $i to the length of the array.

Comment: While it is bad practice (close to criminal) to omit brackets, it should still work since the entire if-else is considered one statement.

Comment: I tried this, but now the loop is not going through the states array.

Comment: @apartridge There are *too many* "**bad practice**"s on SO today: globals, references, singletons, `echo` heredoc / nowdoc, `goto`, etc... And, yeah, how many of us using one or two or all of them? It is nod "bad" while it is not in a curved hands.

Comment: I don't understand all of what you are trying to say. But bad practices are bad for a reason, they tend to cause unneccessary problems. One-liner statements could avoid using brackets, but for multi-lined statements you are bound to get into trouble.

Comment: @apartridge I didn't test the code; it was meant as a starting point. I don't see any errors at a glance but feel free to update it if you have a fix. You'll note that I didn't define the variables that were implied as defined by the OP's script (statecapitalnames, etc).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `break` to leave the `for` loop.

You should look at `array_search` to find the index you are looking for. `array_search` returns `false` if the capital does not exist.

For instance

```
$i = array_search($enteredCity, $stateCapitalNames);
if($i !== false)
{
    echo "<p>$enteredCity is the capital of <b>",$stateNames[$i],"</b>. </p>";
}
```

Comment: Didn't know array_search existed. I like this +1 for a nifty tool.

Comment: This is the approach I would take, but if you were trying to learn how to iterate over the array and quit when you found what you are looking for, then a break is what you want for that.